# Алгоритм на факториалы

Tags: delphi

Стоит задача: написать программу для подсчета значения

> F(m,n)=n!m!/(n+m)!

Для факториалов код написан:

```
var
m,n,F,k,s,i,d: real;
begin
  m:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  n:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  s:=1;
  k:=1;
  while k<=m do
  begin
  k:=k+1;
  s:=s*k;
  end;
  while i<=n do
  begin
  i:=i+1;
  d:=d*i;
  end;
```

А как теперь эти значения забить под функцию? Или можно как-то упростить вышенаписанное? Помогите, пожалуйста, я новичок в этом деле.

Answer (score 4):

Естественно, алгоритм можно упростить.

Во-первых, (n + 1)! = n! * (n + 1). Т.е. можно считать факториалы чисел от 1 до (n + 1) и сохранять каждый следующий факториал в массив, чтобы не пересчитывать его заново.

Во-вторых, n! * k! / (n + k)! можно упростить. (n + k)! = n! * (n + 1) * (n + 2) * ... * (n + k) . Затем факториалы сократить. Дело в том, что факториал очень быстро растет. И очень легко вылезти за разрядную сетку. Сокращая подобные члены, Вы сокращаете необходимость в лишний разрядах :-)

В третьих, для такой задачи выгодно промежуточные значения хранить в целочисленных типах. Действительно, факториал целого числа - всегда целое число. При хранении факториала в вещественных числах, Вы потеряете точность. Что при множестве операций умножения и деления может оказаться фатальным. Поэтому рекомендация - реализовывать свои типы для алгоритмов работы с "большими" числами. Самый простой способ работать с bigint - просто использовать 64-битные типы данных (long long int в C или что-то вроде int64 там же). Либо реализуете свой тип. Например, как массив, в каждом элементе которого хранится один десятичный разряд числа (т.е. число 1243 будет выглядеть как a[1] = 3, a[2] = 4, a[3] = 2, a[4] = 1), но это расточительно по отношению к памяти. Короче, думайте сами и смотрите что Вам нужно конкретно.

В четвертых, странно, но разве вам не говорили, что использование типа real в нынешних условиях бессмысленно? Для чисел с плавающей имеет смысл использование типа double. Быстродействие при этом не пострадает, а точность повысится. Связано это с тем, что real все равно должен преобразоваться в double, а затем, после расчетов, обратно, т.к. разрядность блока работы с вещественными числами в процесооре соответствует разрядности double-чисел.

Comment: @gecube, вы это решили новичку рассказать, который не совсем в курсе, как функции описывать?

Comment: Все правильно. Тут требуется не в знаниие языков программирования или практики кодинга, а в знании школьной программы по математике. С этого нужно начинать - с математики и теории алгоритмов.

Comment: @Dex, ну, если ТС поймет, то это супер, тем более пускай не обольщается, что все якобы просто. Заодно - да, без умение алгоритмизировать, понимания логики и хотя бы базовых знаний математики в программировании делать нечего. Не имеет смысла плодить ряды кодеров :(

Comment: @mikillskegg, как вам сказать, на вопрос "как забить это в функцию" математика не поможет. @gecube, вы несомненно правы, я к тому, что скорее всего вопрос оптимизации стоял в рамках учебной задачи, понятное дело, что факториал можно вычислять многими способами, имхо.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пишете функцию, вычисляющую факториал. В Pascal функции выглядят следующим образом:

```
function factorial(n: integer): integer;
begin
    ...
    result := ...
end;
```

Думаю, что вычислять значение факториала дробного числа вам не нужно (разве что вы не начали с нейронных сетей изучение программирования), посему предлагаю использовать целые числа. В теле функции находится ваш алгоритм (или какой-либо другой).

Вы вызываете свою функцию:

```
var
   res: integer;
...
res = factorial(n)*factorial(m)/factorial(n+m);
```

Так же я бы в вашем алгоритме убрал лишние переменные:

```
s := 1
while m > 0 do
    begin
        s := s * m;
        m := m - 1;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализация факториалов:

```
Factorial(n: integer):integer;
begin
if n<=1 then Result := 1
else Result := N * Factorial(N-1);
end;
```

Реализация функции:

```
F(m,n):integer;
begin
Result := Round((Factorial(m)*Factorial(n))/Factorial(m+n))
end;
```

Вот и все!

p.s. В первом алгоритме достигнута простота кода за счет **Рекурсии**